# Place to unzip files in Android

Tags: android, libgdx, storage, unzip

Because of apk maximum size 50MB, i decided to make apk expansion file. I know that I can get any file (inputstream) from  this package but I am working in LibGDX, and this doesn't have option to load textures/music from inputstream.
So, I must extract files, load texture/music and then I can delete file.
I think that i need max 50MB space and i have two options:

**UNZIP TO:**

1. **ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()**  - it returns internal file, but I can't know how many files can I unzip there, because this storage is shared with all apps.
2. **getExternalStorageDirectory()** - it returns external file, but according to website (developer.android.com) "This directory may not currently be accessible"

Which directory will be best to unpack and **always avaliable**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you tell us, here there are big quantities of data, so in order to improve user experience (not all phones have huge memory and using internal storage may cause your app is uninstalled) you should use [external storage](http://Caution:%20External%20storage%20can%20become%20unavailable%20if%20the%20user%20mounts%20the%20external%20storage%20on%20a%20computer%20or%20removes%20the%20media,%20and%20there's%20no%20security%20enforced%20upon%20files%20you%20save%20to%20the%20external%20storage.%20All%20applications%20can%20read%20and%20write%20files%20placed%20on%20the%20external%20storage%20and%20the%20user%20can%20remove%20them.).

You have to care about couple of things:

- Add permissions to read / write
- Check file availability starting app

**Adding permissions:**

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

**Checking file availability**
And starting the app, be careful and check if external storage is available, and show message otherwise in order to avoid exceptions:

> **Caution:** External storage can become unavailable if the user mounts the external storage on a computer or removes the media, and there's no security enforced upon files you save to the external storage. All applications can read and write files placed on the external storage and the user can remove them.

Comment: Don't use the external storage as that will give other apps access to the content of your file. You will also add an unnecessary permission that you won't really need.

See my answer below for a better solution.

Comment: @ErikHellman have you checked the external storage of some android phone? It's full of app data, accesible? yes, but with permissions. And also there is something called encription... you hear about that? using internal or cache memory is a really bad practice for this case

Comment: On most devices today there is no permission protection on the external storage as it uses the fat filesystem.

Comment: in this case, you have the encription, but as I told you, have you checked your sd card? all data is there... you cannot suppose you app is so important to fill internal memory with this quantity of data....

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of the cache partition. You still have to check if the file is there on startup every time if it is on the sd card (some other app, or the user, might have deleted it). Also, you don't want to encrypt a really large file this way since it will slow down startup a lot.

Finally, just because other apps are doing it wrong doesn't mean you should also do so.

Using the cache partition is the answer here.

Comment: sorry, but who is wrong is you, not almost all androd community. Using internal storage is never encouraged, but use it to store large, permanent and own app files is nearby forbidden.

Comment: Ever checked the official Android docs on this? (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). The data in question is private, encrypting files yourself is highly discouraged on Android (it is slow) and if you would stop and think for a moment, the cache is actually perfect. Extracting a file from the apk expansion file will duplicate the content on the device, thus it shouldn't be store persistently. Putting it in the cache will provide a much better overall user experience as you won't waste system resources.

Comment: dude.... you didn't get the question.... OP want to: **a)** download the expansion file **b)**  extract data to permanent storage, and finally **c)** delete the downloaded expansion file, **the data extracted is persistent** so CACHE IS NOT AN OPTION HERE!

Comment: Normally the expansion file is downloaded at install time. However, your app must also be able to handle download of this file itself at startup in case it didn't complete at the installation time (lost network, user deleted the file etc.). The thing is, you shouldn't delete this file, it will be downloaded again in any case when the app is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Context.getCacheDir()` to get access to a private directory where you can extract files. This should be considered as a cache directory, so you should check for the file on startup and extract it again if it is missing.

This method doesn't require any additional permissions and is more secure. Also, the directory is guaranteed to exist by the Android APIs.

Comment: Ok, but there is one problem - this cache memory is shared bettwen all apps. I heard that old devices had only 150 MB this memory. Let's suppose there are apps that saves their data in this memory and there can be a situation where I won't have so much space to extract files.

Comment: The cache partition is shared by all apps, but each cache folder is private for every app. Just as I wrote in my comment above.

The size is handled by the system, so if your data is removed you only have to put check and extract the file again next time.